# How to redirect url to either the Soundcloud or youtube app if downloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, soundcloud

So when I am wanting to go to the twitter app if the user has it downloaded and safari (a browser) if not. I write this code:

```
NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter://user?screen_name=foo"]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlApp]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
}else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.twitter.com/foo"]];
}
```

if I want to do the same with facebook I do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/TragicClothing"]];
```

But what happens when I want to do this with Soundcloud (and Youtube)?

Is there an equivelant `twitter://user?screen_name=foo` for them both?

> Please bare in mind that I want to go to a user page (`foo`) of Soundcloud (and Youtube)
>
> ---

my code for youtube:

```
NSString *channelName = @"channel";

NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://user/%@",channelName]];
NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/%@",channelName]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
    // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
}
else{
    // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS open YouTube App with query (url schemes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695537/ios-open-youtube-app-with-query-url-schemes)

Comment: I would also like to know the method for soundcloud

Comment: and the question that you think I duplicated only specifies ways to go to a video rather than a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct mode to open an app and check if is installed:

if you have a tex area or label you have to use:

```
NSString *tweetUser;

tweetUser = self.myLabel.text;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://user?screen_name=%@", tweeUser]]];
```

the correct method is:

```
- (IBAction)tweet:(id)sender {

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://app"]]){

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=<neme here>"]];

    }else{

        [self notInstalledAlert];
    }
}

- (UIAlertView*) notInstalledAlert {

    return [[UIAlertView alloc]
            initWithTitle:@"Twitter Not Installed!"
            message:@"Twitter must be installed on the device in order to open app"
            delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

for example youtube have:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://app"]]){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://user/donotrecords"]];
```

this is soundcloud, but you need user ID not name:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"soundcloud://app"]]){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"soundcloud:users:id"]];
```

Comment: I asked for Youtube and Soundcloud not twitter though? The equivelant to `twitter://user?screen_name=`

Comment: is the same for all app you want my is a example you have to search the correct scheme for the single app see my link in my answere

Comment: Ok insert in my post Youtube and Souncloud scheme, but you need a user ID number on sound cloud check the information here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/

Comment: for some reason the soundcloud: `soundcloud://users/123456` (my equivelant) is saying "This link is not supported" and the same sort of thing with youtube

Comment: I have sorted the soundcloud

Comment: It's strange I've tried on my phone before posting the answare :)

Comment: You used my code? Is correct way to use ://app in the xcode

Answer (score 0):

The URL scheme to access a user page in the SoundCloud iOS app is `soundcloud://users/{USER_ID}`.