# Launch YouTube App in iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I have webview displaying youtube video:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.cast.html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

HTML link looks like this:

```
<div class="h_iframe">
<iframe webkit-playsinline height="480" width="2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ru1_lI84Wkw?feature=player_detailpage&playsinline=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

That works perfectly, but i want also to let user to watch it on the youtube app. 
Is it possible to create link in webview that launch YouTube app (if installed on device) ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS open YouTube App with query (url schemes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695537/ios-open-youtube-app-with-query-url-schemes)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL("youtube://XXXXXX")
```

where XXXXXX is the code of the video in youtube.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. But how do I come back to my app. Is there any provision like back button?

Answer (score 27):

Since Youtube isn't pre-installed on the phone, it's a good idea to safeguard this by testing the URL then falling back to using safari if they don't have youtube installed.

Add this key to your info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
   <string>youtube</string>
</array>
```

Then this is the code that will fallback to safari if the Youtube app isn't installed.

```
    let youtubeId = "vklj235nlw"
    var url = URL(string:"youtube://\(youtubeId)")!
    if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)  {
        url = URL(string:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(youtubeId)")!
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: As for iOS 9, you also need the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` set in the `info.plist` to an array containing `youtube` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119595/canopenurl-not-working-in-ios-10

Answer (score 14):

> Update for Swift 3 and iOS 10+

OK, there are two easy steps to achieve this:

First, you have to modify `Info.plist` to list `Youtube` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Simply open `Info.plist` as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>youtube</string>
</array>
```

After that, you can open any Youtube URL inside Youtube application by simply substituting `https://` with `youtube://`. Here is a complete code, you can link this code to any button you have as an Action:

```
@IBAction func YoutubeAction() {

    let YoutubeID =  "Ktync4j_nmA" // Your Youtube ID here
    let appURL = NSURL(string: "youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(YoutubeID)")!
    let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(YoutubeID)")!
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if application.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
        application.open(appURL as URL)
    } else {
        // if Youtube app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        application.open(webURL as URL)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

`UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://youtube.com")!)`

if YouTube app is not installed, it opens Safari (web page)

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru it opens YouTube app when installed; i am using it in a production app that shows trailers for movies or series. I am using iOS 10.2.

Comment: There must be another setting configured. I'm using it in the same configuration and it pops up only Safari.

Comment: Also `openURL()` is deprecated in iOS 10.

Comment: That's weird. Some of my user said that they can't open YouTube by clicking the link in my app. But mine's working well.