# canOpenURL not working in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, info.plist, openurl

The above code is always returning false

```
if {(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!))}
```

I guess this a problem found in iOS10. 
I am trying to open google maps app if there in one installed or try to open apple maps so wanted to use canOpenURL . are there any alternatives

Answer (score 29):

Add this to your Info.plist and then try calling canOpenURL.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Comment: what a great tip, thanks!

Comment: how to get this value "comgooglemaps"?

Comment: As of today, this solution still works on iOS 12-14

Answer (score 4):

### Edit:

The correct key to be used in the app's **plist** file is `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and not `UIDefaultLaunchStoryboard` as stated by Apple's documentation.

### Original answer:

From Apple's documentation:

> If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare the URL
>   schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by using the
>   UIDefaultLaunchStoryboard array in your Xcode project’s Info.plist
>   file. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with this method,
>   add it as a string in this array.
>
> If your (iOS 9.0 or later) app calls this method using a scheme you
>   have not declared, the method returns false, whether or not an
>   appropriate app for the scheme is installed on the device.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl).

Comment: What does this have to do with `UIDefaultLaunchStoryboard`? I think that's a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: Well, you are right. And I'm sorry for not double checking it before posting it but I really didn't expected Apple to have such a mistake present in their documentation. The correct key is `LSApplicationsQueriesSchemes`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Even after adding schemes to `LSApplicationsQueriesSchemes`, this isn't working on iOS10. Any idea?

Comment: there's a typo it is not `LSApplicationsQueriesSchemes` (plural) but `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. i updated the answer

Comment: Thanks!. Also, it seems that Apple's documentation has been fixed.