# Open the youtube app from flutter app on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, youtube

I basically want to open a specific youtube video from my app, when a button is pressed. If the youtube app is installed on the user's device, then the video should be opened in the youtube app (and not in the browser or a separate webview).

I used the `url_launcher` package for that, and it works fine on android. However on iOS the youtube app is not opened even if it is installed, instead a separate web window is opened, where the corresponding youtube url is shown as a webpage.

I thought, that I could override this behaviour like so:

```
_launchURL() async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    if (await canLaunch('youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw')) {
      await launch('youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw');
    } else {
      if (await canLaunch('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw')) {
        await launch('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw');
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw';
      }
    }
  } else {
    const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

but it didn’t work. In case you wonder, I use the following imports:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

I am pretty sure, the `youtube://` URL-Scheme works (launches the YouTube app), because I tested it on third party apps (Launch Center Pro and Pythonista).

The last thing I was not able to test, is if the `Platform.isIOS` is really true on my IPhone.

Is there a working way, to open the YouTube App from flutter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to set `forceSafariVC: false`, because it is true on default, which causes the url to be opened inside a sort of webview inside the app.

```
_launchURL() async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    if (await canLaunch('youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw')) {
      await launch('youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw', forceSafariVC: false);
    } else {
      if (await canLaunch('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw')) {
        await launch('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw');
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw';
      }
    }
  } else {
    const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
}
```

This is actually documented in the `url_launcher` docs, but somewhat hidden...

Comment: canLaunch('youtube://www.youtube…') gives a false
but launch('youtube://www.youtube…') works
forceSafariVC seems false on default?
I’m using flutter 1.7.8 & url_launcher: ^5.0.2 on iOS

Comment: <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>youtube</string>
    </array>
 solved the problem

Comment: As of iOS 9, you also need the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes set in the info.plist to an array containing youtube: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31086148/6024667

Comment: New version of url_launcher doesn't have forceSafariVC option :(

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to have all that *if/else* clauses. The most important thing to take into consideration is that whether the device has the YouTube app or not, regardless of the O.S (*and remember to define your function as Future because of the async*):

```
Future<void> _launchYoutubeVideo(String _youtubeUrl) async {
if (_youtubeUrl != null && _youtubeUrl.isNotEmpty) {
  if (await canLaunch(_youtubeUrl)) {
    final bool _nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launch(
      _youtubeUrl,
      forceSafariVC: false,
      universalLinksOnly: true,
    );
    if (!_nativeAppLaunchSucceeded) {
      await launch(_youtubeUrl, forceSafariVC: true);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

The thing to highlight here to avoid several **if/else** si the attribute *universalLinksOnly* set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. You can try the below code:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';  

    void main() => runApp(const HomePage());  

    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {  
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);  
      @override  
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
        return const MaterialApp(  
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,  
          home: MyApp(),  
        );  
      }  
    }  

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {  
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);  
      @override  
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }  

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {  
      Future<void>? _launched;  
      @override  
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
        const String toLaunch = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcZ8lTRTNM0';  
        return Scaffold(  
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter Demo')),  
          body: Center(  
            child: ElevatedButton(  
              onPressed: () => setState(() {  
                _launched = _launchInBrowser(toLaunch);  
              }),  
              child: const Text('Launch in browser'),  
            ),  
          ), );  
      }  
      Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {  
        if (!await launch(  
          url,  
          forceSafariVC: true,  
          forceWebView: false,  
          headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'},  
        )) {  
          throw 'Could not launch $url';  
        }  
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using same package:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Here is latest working example. Most answers above is outdated or using deprecated package. Default mode is LaunchMode.platformDefault. Change to LaunchMode.externalApplication will open youtube app. Hope this helps

```
Future<dynamic> openUrl(String url, callback) async {
  try {
    if (await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
      callback(true);
    } else {
      toastMessage('#1: Could not launch $url');
      callback(false);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    toastMessage('#2: Could not launch $url');
    callback(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `canLaunch` returns `False` for me, even with the YouTube app installed. You also cannot try-catch the launch, because failure to launch does not raise an exception.

Instead, you can pass in the success / fail status of the _launch() call into .then() and check the value. If it did not launch the app successfully, you can then launch via web browser.

This works for me:

```
void _launchYouTubeVideo(youtubeURL) async {
  String _appURL = youtubeURL;

  // URLs sent to YouTube app can't start with https

  if (_appURL.startsWith("https://")) {
    _appURL = _appURL.replaceFirst("https://", ""); // remove "https://" if it exists
  }

  try {
    await launch('youtube://$_appURL', forceSafariVC: false).then((bool isLaunch) async {
      print('isLaunch: $isLaunch');
      if (!isLaunch) {
        // Launch Success
        print("Launching in browser now ...");
        await launch(youtubeURL);
      } else {
        // Launch Fail
        print("YouTube app Launched!");
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print("An error occurred: $e");
    await launch(youtubeURL);
  }
}
```