# Flutter : open video in YouTube App in iOS version

Tags: ios, flutter, youtube

I have an App contain YouTube videos ,I want to open them in YouTube App ,for android I used android_intent package ,is there same package for IOS ? or another way?
android_intemt code :

```
child: InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
         await intent.launch();
      },
       child: YoutubePlayer(
       controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open the YouTube link (works on iOS as well as Android). If it doesn't open in the YouTube app, try launching a URL starting with `youtube://`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976485/7608627) answer for more details.