# Force YouTube link to open in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, youtube, mobile-safari

I have the opposite problem of [iOS open YouTube App with query (url schemes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695537/ios-open-youtube-app-with-query-url-schemes).

Basically I have a URL such as https://youtu.be/A4yitOx14Bg. When the user taps it, or when I open URL, it normally opens up in the YouTube app. The user can usually customize this behavior with a non-obvious gesture. Namely they can tap and hold the link, and then choose to “Open in YouTube” or “Open in Safari”.

Is there some form of the URL that will always force it to open in mobile Safari, and not require user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

I found this site which has a bunch of different formats: https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486

Pasting it into notes reveals that the only formats that force a page to load into safari are the youtube-nocookie.com urls. This is an official URL from Google, [mentioned here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en#zippy=%2Cturn-on-privacy-enhanced-mode).

Thus the same link above can be changed to https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/A4yitOx14Bg and it’ll forcibly load in mobile Safari.